# Why jenkins custom plugin could not upload file from slave to s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have written a custom jenkins plugin which uploads the artifact in my workspace to s3 bucket. This works fine when i run my job on jenkins master. When my build job is targetted to build from jenkins slave, i get "file not found error" even if file is present in slave directory with exactly the same name. Why it is happening and how can i fix this.

I am exactly using the same code in my plugin as in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

For your information my jenkins master runs as "jenkins" user in master and when slave jobs run, they run as "jenkins-slave" user in slave machine. Both as ubuntu machines.

I think i have know the cause of the problem:

Code as in Jenkins plugin:
`public void perform(Run<?,?> build, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener) {
    ...
    String filePath = workspace.getRemote();
    File file = new File(filePath);
    System.out.println(" File exists? :" + file.exists());
    System.out.println(" File is directory? :"+file.isDirectory());
    System.out.println(" file is file? :"+ file.isFile());

    ....
    }`
returns `true false true` when run on jenkins master. and returns `false false false` when run on jenkins slave. 
When printing workspace.getRemote() returns correct path to file as in filePath. How to fix this.

Comment: It makes things easier for ppl if you post your code here.

Comment: Not sure it's about s3 - can you just copy file or print it while running your plugin from slave? How the file is created before you trying to upload it?

Comment: @RomanNo, its not forming the file Object in first place. Though prints the correct path to file in slave.

Comment: @patrick My code contains a little more stuff pertaining to perform method for jenkins plugin and is exactly the same as in link above. Didn't felt like adding value pasting all code again.

Comment: Hello experts... someone suggest please.